# Imprimir resultado de varios checkboxes al mismo tiempo

Tags: javascript, html5

Necesito imprimir los tres resultados al mismo tiempo, pero en el momento de seleccionar los 3 checkboxes solo me muestra un resultado, que es el primer `if`.

Ya validé y no sigue hacia los demás `if`. Anteriormente lo había intentado usando una sola variable resultado pero me presentaba el mismo problema.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function calcular() {
        var res1, res2, res3, num1, num2;

        num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('numero1').value);
        num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('numero2').value);
        //alert('Numero 1: ' + num1);
        //alert('Numero 2: ' + num2);

        if (document.getElementById('checkbox1').checked) {
            res1 = num1 + num2;
            document.write(res1);
        }

        if (document.getElementById('checkbox2').checked) {
            res2 = num1 - num2;
            document.write(res2);
        }

        if (document.getElementById('checkbox3').checked) {
            res3= num1 * num2;
            document.write(res3);
        }
    }


</script>
<form>
    Numero 1: 
    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="numero1"><br><br>
    Numero 2: 
    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="numero2"><br><br>

    Suma <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
    Resta <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2">
    Multiplicación <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3">
    <br>
    <br>

    <input type="button" name="submit" value="Realizar operación" onClick="calcular()">
    <input type="reset" value="borrar">

</form>
```

Comment: y si pruebas mejor pintarlo dentro de un elemento html ? digamos un div

Comment: imprimo los res en un div?

Comment: osea se me ocurre como 3 contenedores cada uno que tenga adentro el valor de cada respuesta, ahora mismo estás borrando todos los elementos del DOM y no tiene como mucho sentido.

Comment: DOM? . no entiendo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Que tal si lo agregas en el html así:

```js
function calcular() {
  var res1, res2, res3, num1, num2;

  num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('numero1').value);
  num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('numero2').value);
  //alert('Numero 1: ' + num1);
  //alert('Numero 2: ' + num2);

  if (document.getElementById('checkbox1').checked) {
    res1 = num1 + num2;
    document.getElementById('resultado1').innerHTML = res1;
  }

  if (document.getElementById('checkbox2').checked) {
    res2 = num1 - num2;
    document.getElementById('resultado2').innerHTML = res2;
  }

  if (document.getElementById('checkbox3').checked) {
    res3 = num1 * num2;
    document.getElementById('resultado3').innerHTML = res3;

  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  Numero 1:
  <input type="text" name="nombre" id="numero1"><br><br> Numero 2:
  <input type="text" name="nombre" id="numero2"><br><br> Suma <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1"> Resta <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2"> Multiplicación <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3">
  <br>
  <br>


  <input type="button" name="submit" value="Realizar operación" onClick="calcular()">
  <input type="reset" value="borrar">

  <div id='resultado1'></div>
  <div id='resultado2'></div>
  <div id='resultado3'></div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

¡Sony, lo que esta pasando en tu código es que cuando un ***if*** cumple la condición inmediatamente muestra esa respuesta por eso es que cuando los seleccionas y muestras los resultados solo muestra la primera condición ya que el imprime cada ves que es verdadero.

Una forma simple de que muestre las 3 respuestas es colocando el `document.write` al final con los 3 valores algo asi `document.write(res1,res2,res3)` pero si alguno de estos valores es indefinido te va a mostrar ***undefined***, otra manera pueden ser hacerlo con un array:

```js
function calcular() {
        var num1, num2;
        var respuestas = [];
        num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('numero1').value);
        num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('numero2').value);
        //alert('Numero 1: ' + num1);
        //alert('Numero 2: ' + num2);

        if (document.getElementById('checkbox1').checked) {
            respuestas.push('Suma: ' + num1+num2)
        }

        if (document.getElementById('checkbox2').checked) {
            respuestas.push('Resta: ' + parseInt(num1-num2))
            
        }

        if (document.getElementById('checkbox3').checked) {
             respuestas.push('Multiplicacion: ' + num1*num2)
            
        }
        document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = respuestas;
    }
```

```html
<form>
    Numero 1: 
    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="numero1"><br><br>
    Numero 2: 
    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="numero2"><br><br>

    Suma <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">
    Resta <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2">
    Multiplicación <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3">
    <br>
    <br>

    <input type="button" name="submit" value="Realizar operación" onClick="calcular()">
    <input type="reset" value="borrar">

</form>
<br>
<label>Operaciones basicas</label>
<div id="res"></div>
```

Espero te sea de ayuda.